# UnityException: Unable to install APK! Installation failed. See the Console for details

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I got this error message when trying to build and run on Android actual device.

[image]

```
UnityException: Unable to install APK!
Installation failed. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.UploadAndStartPlayer (System.String manifestName, System.String stagingArea, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, System.String packageName, Boolean devPlayer, Boolean retryUpload)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Can you post the messages in the Editor Log? If you go to the console tab, and click the little drop down on the top right of the window, it'll show a list with an option to open the Editor Log. Inside this, look for "***" (3 asterisks, without the quotes). It should then take you to the area where the error messages are. (just scroll above or below to find it). Post that here and we can take a look

Answer (score 3):

Try to increase your bundle version code. if your phone has lower bundle version code is not possible to insttall.

Answer (score 0):

- set your Android SDK under Unity 3D
- connect your phone and set also under developement mode under phone Settings.